# why and how __call__ is invoked in python decorators

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
class myDecorator(object):

    def __init__(self, f):
        print "inside myDecorator.__init__()"
        f() # Prove that function definition has completed

    def __call__(self):
        print "inside myDecorator.__call__()"

@myDecorator
def aFunction():
    print "inside aFunction()"

def main():
    print "main starts....."
    aFunction()
    print "main ends....."
```

**Output :**

```
inside myDecorator.__init__()
inside aFunction()
main starts.....
inside myDecorator.__call__()
main ends.....
```

I could not understand following points about above code:

1. Why "main starts...." is not first line to be printed?
2. Suppose if i'm returning some value from aFunction() then it would not be available in place of its call because `aFunction()` is replaced with `inside myDecorator.__call__()` not `inside aFunction()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The decorator syntax:

```
@myDecorator
def aFunction():
    …
```

is equivalent to this:

```
def aFunction():
    …
aFunction = myDecorator(aFunction)
```

If `myDecorator` is a class, then you would expect `__init__` to get called when the function is defined. The instance of the class is then used in place of the function. When you call it, you would expect `__call__` to be called, so that’s where the call to `f()` should go.

Comment: how to call f() from _call_() ? i passed f as a _call_(self, f) parameter and invoking f() , but giving TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: It is worth noting that function-definition is a *statement*, and it is executed like any other statement. This behavior is surprising if you think about function as some sort of definition/declaration.

Comment: @naveenyadav try `self.f = f` inside `__init__`. Don't call f() there.

Comment: tried to call aFunction() from _call_ like :: inside _init_ : self.f=f and inside _call_ self.f(). It worked.

Answer (score 2):

A function definition in Python

```
def foo():
    pass
```

is actually a programmer-friendly way to say something like (pseudocode)*:

```
foo = function(code=compile('pass', ...), globals=globals(), name='foo')
```

so a wrapper simply gets in between:

```
foo = my_wrapper(function(...))
```

if the wrapper is a class, `__init__` will get called. if it's a function, it will be called. After this statement, everything works as usual.

---

*this pseudocode is not that far from real code:

```
>>> def bar(): pass
...
>>> body = compile('print("hello")', '', 'exec')
>>> function = type(bar)
>>> foo = function(body, globals(), 'foo')
>>> foo()
hello
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old quesiton which I found by search. However, I find the accepted answer not entirely satisfactory.

Consider the normal way to write a decorator in Python:

```
def deco(f):
    def g(*args, **kwargs):
        print('boilerplate code')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return g

@deco
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

add(1, 2)
```

In this example, the line `add(1, 2)` is effectively calling `deco(add)(1, 2)`.

Pay special attention to the way we write the line `@deco`: there are no parentheses in this line.

Now we write the equivalent decorator class with one argument added as the class attribute.

```
class Deco:
    def __init__(self, x=1):
        self.x = x
    def __call__(self, f):
        def g(*args, **kwargs):
            print('boilerplate code, x is', self.x)
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return g

@Deco(5)
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

add(1, 2)
```

Now the line `add(1, 2)` is effectively calling `Deco(5)(add)(1, 2)`.

Notice that I have defined the `x` attribute as optional. This means we can write

```
@Deco()
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

in this case.

Pay attention to the way we can write the line `@Deco()` this case, and the line `@deco` in the example above. They have very different meaning:

1. one is `Deco()(add)(1, 2)`,
2. the other one is `deco(add)(1, 2)`.